# Slow download speed from own web server WAMP

Tags: performance, wamp

I set up an easy WAMP server where I have some video files in the www folder. Now, when I download I only get 6-12 MB/s in Opera or Google Chrome. I've done speedtests and I have around 800 MB/s upload (Sweden). What is limiting my download speed from my own server?

Comment: `WAMP` is very general... What package, which version, any "security software" installed?

Comment: I downloaded WampServer yesterday. Apache 2.4.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideas (you don't give enough specifics, really):

- Slow machine?
- Reading from (serving files from) and writing to (download writing to) same hard drive at same time without sufficient buffering?
- Downloading locally or going all the way out to the internet and back    (i.e., using external IP address for your server or local LAN one or 127.0.0.1)?  Speedtest is not relevant if not going out to Internet!

Comment: Sorry, didn't really know what information is needed. I write and read from the same HDD with around 100 MB/s when I did sequential test on CrystalDiskMark. What do you mean by sufficient buffering?

Downloading by entering my IP address in Chrome and then clicking on the file.

Comment: I figured it out. You were right about the HDD. It was the limiting factor. Which I didn't think it would be 'cause it was only 6 MB/s but I checked in Task Manager and disk usage was at 98%.